# Error code 1170, SQL state 42000: BLOB/TEXT column 'token' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql

I have created a MYSQL table which contain table has two columns (user_id,token)
this table will store the GCM tokens of the devices for each user

> user_id is integer and token is text

I made token as TEXT because I do not know the size of the token
but when I try to make the two columns unique like this

```
ALTER TABLE user_account_device_token ADD UNIQUE idx_row_unique(user_id,token);
```

the error appear as the title of this question.
what should I do with this problem?
I read the old questions but no answer match my problem
I appreciate any help.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little bug:

You must specify the length of char in the Text field for using the index. In my sample they use 100 chars for the index. The maximum length ist 767 for a text field.

```
ALTER TABLE user_account_device_token ADD UNIQUE
idx_row_unique(user_id,token(100));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for reply but is the 100 you suggest to be the length of token column or just to the index because the values stored into the token column is not limited

Comment: is the length of chars using for the index. so in my example, if you have data in it that will be different only after 100 chars mysql found both records and must select it with compare. There is no difference in result. Or lets say (only) you have 100 word all start with A and you say the index is 1. then mysql cant findthe record over the index. they found all 100 and then use compare to find the right one

Comment: Nice and one more question please in this way can you said that the token field can store text with 1000 chars ?

Comment: yes they can.  A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 - 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters. Each TEXT value is stored using a two-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done, MariaDB creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to hold values M characters long.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks so much bro.